# What is the recommended process to ask for a review of an updated question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My original question here: [Model Selection in Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155931/the-scientific-method-and-model-selection-in-physics) was put on hold because it was too broad. I  understand the reasons behind the decision, and have updated the question subsequently with several edits to make it hopefully narrower in scope.

What is the recommended way to proceed for after making such edits? Has Physics SE established a site-specific process to ask for a review of such decisions?

Comment: It's the same as every other SE site: your edit pushes it into the review queue. Once there, it takes 5 members with >3000 rep to agree to reopen it.

Comment: You could take the hint that if the answer won't contain any equations it's probably not going to be a popular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kyle mentioned in a comment, each edit after your post is put on hold automatically pushes it into the review queue. So the recommended way to proceed is to **wait** for enough high-rep site members to review your post. If you've fixed the problems that caused it to be put on hold in the first place, it will be reopened by their votes.

I'm not sure if this is accessible to non-moderators, but [here is the outcome of the most recent review on your post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/67754). You have made some edits since then, so right now your post is back in the queue awaiting additional reviews.

Comment: That link is visible to me at 10k+ rep. I also recall looking at those at 3k+ rep as well, not sure if that's the threshold though.